# How to get Firefox to not continue to show "Transferring data from..." in browser status bar after async data is loaded?

Tags: c#, silverlight, firefox

The following **silverlight** demo loads and displays a text file from a server.

However, in **Firefox** (but not Explorer or Chrome) after you click the button and the text displays, the **status bar** continues to show "**Transferring data from test.development...**" which erroneously gives the user the belief that something is still loading.

I've noticed that if you click on another Firefox **tab** and then back on the original one, the message goes away, so it seems to be just a Firefox bug that doesn't clear the status bar automatically.

**Is there a way to clear the status bar automatically in Firefox? or a way to explicitly tell it that the async loading is finished so it can clear the status bar itself?**

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestLoad1111.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 10">
            <Button Content="Load Text" Click="Button_LoadText_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestLoad1111
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region ViewModelProperty: Message
        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }

            set
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_LoadText_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient webClientTextLoader = new WebClient();
            webClientTextLoader.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://test.development:111/testdata/test.txt?" + Helpers.GetRandomizedSuffixToPreventCaching()));
            webClientTextLoader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClientTextLoader_DownloadStringCompleted);
        }


        void webClientTextLoader_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Message = e.Result;
        }

        #region INotifiedProperty Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public static class Helpers
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        public static int GetRandomizedSuffixToPreventCaching()
        {
            return random.Next(10000, 99999);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to file a bug on [Firefox's bug tracking system](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi), and wait until they fix it. You'll need to create an account there, however. There's a chance that your problem is related to the [problem with flash and AJAX](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490235).

Comment: thanks I added a comment and link to this page in the comments on that bug report

Comment: This is something bothering me 4 long a time.. i hope firefox will come up with some solution to it.